# calling a function in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have Inventory table in my Parse database with two relevant fields How can I do that with swift ? I create cloud code with Js below

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("retrieveproducts", function(request, response) {
  var productDictionary ={};
  var query = new Parse.Query("Post");
  query.each(
     function(result){
        var num = result.get("quantity");
        if(result.get("productid") in productDictionary){
             productDictionary[result.get("productid")] += num;
        }
        else{
             productDictionary[result.get("productid")] = num;
        }
    }, {
        success: function() {
            response.success(productDictionary);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error("Query failed. Error = " + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

I want to call this function : but i have some trouble calling it with this call

```js
let params = ["productid": String(), "string": String()]
  
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("retrieveproducts", withParameters: params) {
            (ratings, error) in
            if (error == nil) {
                print("\(params)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the trouble is? What kind of error you're getting? The first thing that comes to mind is that you're passing blank strings to your cloud code. Wanna also add exactly what you wanna have happen?

Comment: Your answer on that post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580356/group-by-sum-aggregate-query-with-parse-swift?rq=1) I created before but no one answered me :

Comment: I don't have any error, but I don't have any data too, and that's not possible...

Answer (score 0):

Swift Code

```
let reportedId = "someUsersObjectId"
    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("suspendUser", withParameters: ["userId": reportedId]) {
                            (result, error) in
                            if (error == nil) {
                                print(result)
                            }
                        }
```

Cloud Code:

```
  Parse.Cloud.define("suspendUser", function(request, response) {
      Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()
      //var User = Parse.Object.extend(Parse.User);
        //var user = new User();
        //user.id = request.params.userId;
        user = new Parse.User({id:request.params.userId})
        user.fetch().then(function() {
                user.set("suspended", true)
                user.save().then(function(newMostRecentAgain) {
                    response.success("Cloud code called! " + request.params.userId)
                  }, function(error) {
                  // The save failed.  Error is an instance of Parse.Error.
                  })
            });
      });
```

So let me walk you through what's going on here, so you can better figure out how to do your code (since I can'e exactly know what you wanna do).

1: in my Swift code, withParameters is how you pass info to your cloud code, and it's in the style of a dictionary. Here I'm passing the user I wanna report's objectId.

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("suspendUser", withParameters: ["userId": reportedId]) {
```

2: In my Cloud code, I'm getting the Parse Object of the user I reported with the objectId I'm passing with the params. Since you can't pass an entire object to the cloud code, I'm rebuilding the object with the objectId and the user.Fetch() you see.

```
user = new Parse.User({id:request.params.userId})
```

3: in my Cloud code, after I successfully save my user after changing it's value for "suspended", I send a string back to the IOS user.

```
response.success("Cloud code called! " + request.params.userId)
```

4: Finally, in my Swift Code, I then print the returned string from success

```
print(result)
```

Does this make things a little bit more clear? Let me know if anything doesn't make sense.